# how do i find out which network profile is currently connected to wifi using netsh command on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, netsh

I went through the documentation of netsh and couldnt find how  to get the name of the profile that is currently connected.
Appriciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

Will show the WiFi interfaces on the system, and if one of them is currently connected, will display the profile name in its output.

Comment: this is wireless interfaces.

Comment: @Richard, the question specified wifi. If you'd like other interfaces, you could try the command

`netsh int show int`

Answer (score 1):

Open the command prompt in administrator mode. Type “cmd” in the Run box, right-click the command prompt icon and choose Run as Administrator (see how). Now enter the following command and hit enter to see the WiFi password.

```
netsh wlan show profile name=labnol key=clear
```

Remember to replace labnol with the name of your Wireless SSID (this is the name of the Wi-Fi network that you connect your computer to). The password will show up under the Security Setting section.

If you would only like to see the password and not the other information, use the findstr command:

```
netsh wlan show profile name=labnol key=clear | findstr Key
```